# Is Oracle SQL WITH statement better than subselect

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, common-table-expression, query-performance

I have an Oracle query that is over 1000 lines long.  Breaking it up and/or using stored procedures is not an option here.  I am about to make it even longer.  Which of these has better performance?  I find the WITH version easier to read.

```
  /* subselect */
  select col01
        ,col02
  from (
    select case col01 when 'X' then 1 else 2 end col01
          ,case col02 when 'Y' then 3 else 4 end col02
    from (      
      select upper(col01) col01
            ,upper(col02) col02
      from (      
        select 'x' as col01
              ,'y' as col02
        from dual
      )
    )
  )
  ;
  ---------------------------------------
  /* with statement */
  with qry01 as (
  select 'x' as col01
        ,'y' as col02
  from dual
  )
  ,qry02 as (
  select upper(col01) col01
        ,upper(col02) col02
  from qry01      
  )
  ,qry03 as (
  select case col01 when 'X' then 1 else 2 end col01
        ,case col02 when 'Y' then 3 else 4 end col02
  from qry02      
  )
  select col01
        ,col02
  from qry03      
  ;
```

Comment: The performance should be essentially the same.  The Oracle optimizer determines the best query plan.  It might be slightly more flexible with CTEs (allowing materialization), but that shouldn't matter if the CTE is only referenced once.

Comment: You cannot determine query performance by looking at it or asking on the internets; the only way to know for sure is test. I guess these aren't your actual queries either.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio. This simplified version is, well simplified.  I was just looking for suggestions before spending hours to transform it from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find the CTE `WITH` expression easier to read. Apart from that there are reasons to prefer it.

- You can use CTE subqueries several times in your main query.
- The Oracle Optimizer can store the result of an CTE subquery in a temporary table which is created on-the-fly. (Note, you can even force it by undocumented hint `/*+ MATERIALIZE */`)
- You can use CTE recursively, see [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2)

Comment: I believe the second point is also true for a non-CTE subquery.

Comment: @trincot, I don't know, seems to be not so clear: [Materialize a Subquery without using "with" clause](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1134148) - don't mix "materialization" with "merge query"

Comment: I am not talking about the forcing part (let alone about "merge query"), but about "The Oracle Optimizer *can* ...". I believe it can.